# No message to receive even though poll() says there is a message

Tags: c, sockets, recv

I have a basic socket connection set up, where I have written code for a server. I am, temporarily, just using Google Chrome with localhost to test out if my code can receive messages properly.

I had some issues with `recv()` blocking, so I used `poll()`, as I saw suggested online, and after doing a quick search on the differences between `select()` and `poll()`.

My code is able to retrieve the message, but `poll()` still thinks that there is a message to read even though there is apparently not (because `recv()` is blocking).

Here is my simplified code:

```c
/*
request is a pointer to a struct with the following members:
char *data;
int size;
*/
request->data = (char *)malloc(1);
char *data_ptr = request->data;
if (request->data == NULL)
{
    perror("Error allocating memory");
    return 8;
}
request->size = 1;
struct pollfd fds[1];
struct pollfd read;
read.fd = *connectionptr;
read.events = POLL_IN | POLL_PRI;
fds[0] = read;
int available_ops = poll(fds, 1, 0);
while (available_ops > 0)
{
    if (fds[0].revents & POLL_IN || fds[0].revents & POLL_PRI)
    {
        if (recv(*connectionptr, data_ptr, 1, 0) < 0)
        {
            perror("Error receiving data");
            return 6;
        }
        request->data = (char *)realloc(request->data, request->size + 1);
        request->size++;
        data_ptr = request->data + request->size - 1;
        if (request->data == NULL)
        {
            perror("Error allocating mem");
            return 8;
        }
    }
    available_ops = poll(fds, 1, 0);
    printf("Read %s thus far, %d characters more to read\n", request->data, available_ops);
}
```

Running this, I get a final output (the last print statement that is run's output) of the following:

```
Read GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:443
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
sec-ch-ua: "Not.A/Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="114", "Google Chrome";v="114"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9

thus far, 1 characters more to read
```

After this, the program stalls, and by checking the debugger I see that it is the `recv()` (in the sample code above, but shown below again for convenience) that is blocking the flow.

```c
// ... is indicating that there is stuff before/after it
...if (recv(*connectionptr, data_ptr, 1, 0) < 0)...
```

The socket is configured with keep alive (I tried disabling this, because I thought it might be the problem, but it didn't work) and address reuse.

---

**Edit:**

Following is the full code up to the problem (code after the problem has been excluded), as I was told that this isn't enough to fulfill the need to be reproducible:

```c
#include "server.h"

int main(void)
{
    int socket_desc = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (socket_desc < 0)
    {
        perror("Error initializing socket");
        close(socket_desc);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Socket created\n");
    int reuse = 1;
    int keep_alive = 1;
    if (setsockopt(socket_desc, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &reuse, sizeof(reuse)) < 0)
    {
        perror("Socket Address Reuse could not be set");
        close(socket_desc);
        return 2;
    }
    printf("Socket set to reuse address\n");
    if (setsockopt(socket_desc, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &keep_alive, sizeof(keep_alive)) < 0)
    {
        perror("Keep Alive could not be activated");
        close(socket_desc);
        return 3;
    }
    printf("Socket set to keep connection alive\n");
    struct sockaddr_in6 address;
    memset(&address, 0, sizeof(address));
    address.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
    address.sin6_port = htons(443);
    address.sin6_addr = in6addr_any;
    int binding = bind(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address));
    if (binding < 0)
    {
        perror("Bind failed");
        close(socket_desc);
    }
    printf("Socket bound to port 443\n");
    if (listen(socket_desc, 5) < 0)
    {
        perror("Error in listening");
        close(socket_desc);
        return 4;
    }
    printf("Listening...\n");
    struct sockaddr client_info = {0};
    socklen_t client_info_length = sizeof(client_info);
    int soc_conn = accept(socket_desc, &client_info, &client_info_length);
    if (soc_conn < 0)
    {
        perror("Error accepting connection to client");

        close(socket_desc);
        return 5;
    }
    struct chararr receive_buffer;
    int code = process_request(&soc_conn, &receive_buffer);
    if (code != 0)
    {
        free(receive_buffer.data);
        close(socket_desc);
        close(soc_conn);
        return code;
    }

    printf("Message Sent!\n");
    printf("ending program...\n");
    close(socket_desc);
    close(soc_conn);
    free(receive_buffer.data);
    return 0;
}

int process_request(int *connectionptr, struct chararr *request)
{
    request->data = (char *)malloc(1);
    char *data_ptr = request->data;
    if (request->data == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error allocating memory");
        return 8;
    }
    request->size = 1;
    printf("Receiving Data\n");
    struct pollfd fds[1];
    struct pollfd readcheck;
    readcheck.fd = *connectionptr;
    readcheck.events = POLL_IN | POLL_PRI;
    fds[0] = readcheck;
    int available_ops = poll(fds, 1, 0);
    while (available_ops > 0)
    {
        
        if (fds[0].revents & POLL_IN || fds[0].revents & POLL_PRI)
        {
            if (recv(*connectionptr, data_ptr, 1, 0) < 0)
            {
                perror("Error receiving data");
                return 6;
            }
            request->data = (char *)realloc(request->data, request->size + 1);
            request->size++;
            data_ptr = request->data + request->size - 1;
            if (request->data == NULL)
            {
                perror("Error allocating mem");
                return 8;
            }
        }
        available_ops = poll(fds, 1, 0);
        printf("Read %s thus far, %d characters more to read\n", request->data, available_ops);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

server.h:

```c
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <poll.h>

struct chararr
{
    char *data;
    int size;
};

int process_request(int *connectionptr, struct chararr *request);
```

Comment: Aside: Naming a variable `read` which is the same name as a library function isn't a good idea.

Comment: @pmacfarlane Thank you for the pointer. I will change the variable in my actual code.

Comment: You're assuming that `realloc()` will return the same pointer, but with more storage allocated. This is not always true, it could return a completely different pointer. So your `data_ptr++` logic is flawed.

Comment: You initialize `*data_ptr = request->data;`, but you `realloc()` `request->data` each byte read. That creates a new buffer and frees the old one, which `data_ptr` is pointing to - `data_ptr` never points to the resized buffer (probably - it's undefined behaviour so you might get lucky sometimes). This example is a very inefficient way to read bytes so I assume the actual code is different, but this is something to watch for.

Comment: What is the point to use `poll()` for a single file descriptor? You can `recv()` with `MSG_DONTWAIT` or set descriptor to non-blocking mode.

Comment: @dimich I don't want to set the whole thing to non-blocking mode, and I haven't seen that flag before in the documentation (https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/recv.html#)

Comment: Did you want a timeout of 0? That will return immediately even with nothing to read, -1 will block.

Comment: @JohnBayko Embarrassingly, I was not aware of this. As my name suggests, I am still learning, and I thank you for bringing this to my attention. I had thought that the newly allocated buffer would just be the old one but adding on some extra memory to the end. I will re-assign the data_ptr each time the realloc is called in the code. Also, is the inefficiency due to reading 1 byte at a time because I thought by doing this less resources would be used?

Comment: @JohnBayko I wanted the timeout to be as small as possible to reduce the amount of time wasted waiting, so I set 0 as the timeout. (In this example, I am just using poll to know when there is no more to read)

Comment: You don't exit the loop anywhere, unless there's an error. Does the real code have a length check or flag in the data to indicate the end?

Comment: Yes, sorry. The real code leaves the loop when no message has been found. The >= 0 and ==0 parts were just remanants of me trying to find a bug. I will update this now.

Comment: @AmLearning Maybe take the address of an index into the data buffer, rather than try to keep a pointer updated. The index can just be incremented, it'll be simpler.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but `POLL_PRI` does not indicate data is available, so you might be blocking because of that.

Comment: @JohnBayko Removing the checking for POLL_PRI did something strange as now the same message is seemingly infinitely printing. poll() shows one more character is to be read, but the output seems to be the same after reaching completion (where completion is what was shown in the original example). recv() is no longer blocking however this new problem has arose.

Comment: @JohnBayko Nevermind, I simply forgot to eliminated the POLL_PRI in the configuration of poll() (I only removed it from my if statement). This seems to have solved the problem of recv() blocking. If you post an answer I can accept it.

Comment: @JohnBayko Also, could you explain why POLL_PRI doesn't mean something is there, because the documentation says that if POLL_PRI is triggered it means that high-priority data is available for reading.

Comment: There is no 'time wasted waiting'. `poll()` returns when there is data to be read, or EOS, or an error. You aren't testing for EOS BTW. `poll()` combined with blocking sockets has many issues: do not use. Just use a read timeout (`SO_RCVTIMEO`).

Comment: @AmLearning `POLL_PRI` can indicate out of band data, that is data used to manage the connection, but it's not data that `recv()` would read.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided a reproducible example, I can't say that this answer contains a fix, but I see these problems:

#### `realloc()` can return a different pointer

Your code calls `realloc()` like so:

```c
    request->data = (char *)realloc(request->data, request->size + 1);
```

However, you're also maintaining another variable, `data_ptr`, which points into your buffer.

`realloc()` can return a different pointer than was passed to it. So you'll need to abandon your `data_ptr` idea. Instead, track the number of bytes you have read so far, and use that as an index into your current buffer pointer (which can change via the `realloc()`).

Dereferencing the `data_ptr` pointer if `realloc()` gave you a different pointer will invoke undefined behaviour. This could well be the source of your problems.

#### Increasing your allocation by one byte at a time

This is incredibly inefficient. You should allocate as many bytes as you think you might need in a typical case, and if you overflow it, double the size of the allocation. Repeat if necessary.

#### Reading one byte at a time

This is incredibly inefficient. You should try to read as many bytes as are free in your current buffer. If you fill it, double the size of the buffer, and keep reading (until you get no more bytes).

#### Don't use the same name as library functions

You have a variable called `read`, which is also the name of a library function. Don't do that. I'm somewhat surprised the compiler didn't complain.

Your read loop should probably resemble something like this. I've omitted error checking and even the `poll()` stuff.

```c
size_t buff_size = 8192u;
char *buffp = malloc(buff_size);
size_t bytes_read = 0u;
ssize_t slurp;

while ((slurp = recv(fd, buffp + bytes_read, buff_size - bytes_read, 0)) > 0)
{
    bytes_read += slurp;
    if (bytes_read == buff_size)
    {
        buff_size *= 2u;
        buffp = realloc(buffp, buff_size);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have changed the `read` variable to a different name. I tried changing the `data_ptr++;` to `data_ptr = request->data + request->size - 1;` but I am still getting the same issue of recv stalling. I will implement your suggestions for the allocation and reading sizes. Thank you!

Comment: *It seems likely that you need to zero out the revents part of the structure before calling poll().* No need to do that.

Comment: @Shawn Does `poll()` zero the `revents` field for fds that don't have activity? If so I'll revert the answer.

Comment: Yes, of course it does.

Comment: @Shawn That wasn't obvious to me. e.g using `select()` you have to construct the set each time. I've not really used `poll()`.

Comment: It was invented to correct many of `select()`'s issues including that need to reinitialize the watchlist every time it's called.

Comment: Doubling the size of the buffer with each iteration will result in UB once `buff_size` overflows, which isn't hard to do with just an `int` variable.

Comment: @AndrewHenle They are making a web server, and reading the HTTP request.

Comment: @pmacfarlane And HTTP request can be a POST of a large amount of data...

Comment: @AndrewHenle Perhaps - but I doubt it is the problem the OP faces. Is there a limit to the size of an HTTP request? What datatype do we need?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Changed to use `size_t`.